# C# to search duplicates in two strings and write unique value to variable

Tags: c#

Text 1 : 
%start : this is start : %End 
%start : this is different : %End
%start : this is start 2: %End 
.
;
;
n

Text 2 :
%start : this is start 3: %End 
%start : this is start : %End
%start : this is different : %End
.
;
;
n

Result Should be :
%start : this is start : %End 
%start : this is different : %End
%start : this is start 2: %End 
%start : this is start 3: %End

Compare Text 1 and Text 2 , Provide unique values in result. Data in both text always lies between tags %start and %End.

Comment: Sounds great, what is your question? :-)

Comment: I need to compare data from text1 and text2 by using tags(%start and %End). Write all the data from text1 to result and data from text2 should only be written to result, If it is unique compared to text1 data.

Comment: Add all the strings to a List<string>, and then list.Distinct()

Comment: @bHaRaThN: We are asking **what you have tried** (your code examples), not what you are hoping to accomplish.

Comment: Trying to answer a question that changes every few seconds is like throwing a bee at a running puppy, so if it could stop changing that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Linq`. Just create two `List<string>` then join two `List` using `Union` method. **This method excludes duplicates from the return set.**. More details please check [Enumerable.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx).

Code#1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list1 =new List<string>();
        list1.Add("%start : this is start : %End");
        list1.Add("%start : this is different : %End");
        list1.Add("%start : this is start 2: %End");

        List<string> list2 =new List<string>();
        list2.Add("%start : this is start 3: %End");
        list2.Add("%start : this is start : %End");
        list2.Add("%start : this is different : %End");

        List<string> list3 = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
        foreach(string item in list3){
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Code#2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list1 =new List<string>();
        list1.Add("text 1");
        list1.Add("text 2");
        list1.Add("text 3");

        List<string> list2 =new List<string>();
        list2.Add("text 4");
        list2.Add("text 1");
        list2.Add("text 2");
        list2.Add("text 5");

        List<string> list3 = list1.Union(list2).ToList();
        foreach(string item in list3){
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Please check [example in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V44w3x)

Comment: I'd say using a `Set` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The question says these are each singular strings, which contain multiple %start/%end pairs.   The fun thing is, those are red herrings you can ignore.  That's not what really separates your substring values.

Your instructor has accidentally punched a hole in the assignment by having the character ':' between the value substrings and the start/end indicators. If you use this to split your values and you throw out any characters in the resulting array that have `%` in them, you can just artificially put the start/end pairs back when you roll your output.

Given that Text 1 is a string called text1 and Text 2 is a string called text2:

```
List<string> result = new List<string();
//use Split() to get string arrays
var a = text1.Split(":");
var b = text2.Split(":");

foreach(var s in a)
{
   if(!a.Contains("%"))
      result.Add("%start : " + a + ": %End");
}
foreach(var s in b)
{
   if(!b.Contains("%"))
      result.Add("%start : " + b + ": %End");
}

return result.Distinct();
```

It'd be a little kludgy in a production environment, but in this case it's functional.

Comment: OP completely changed his example. It's much easier, so you might want to update your answer :)

Comment: I've done the homework for someone to my quota of once today lol